# Scatter plot Error: too many indices for array

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using Logistic regression model to predict the age of person who buy a product. To show in a plot i am using matplotlib scatter plot but there is a problem in taking argument which gives an error for too many indices`

```
# Visualising the Training set results
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
x_set, y_set = x_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = x_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = x_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = x_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = x_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))

plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))

plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):

    plt.scatter(x_set[(y_set == j),0], x_set[(y_set == j),1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Logistic Regression (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Estimated Salary')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out the values for `x_set[(y_set == j),0], x_set[(y_set == j),1]`?

Comment: yes i have tried with all variables but the code is persist

Comment: Can you share what you got? We can't debug your code because we don't know what any of your variables are. Otherwise create a minimal but complete example code to test.